# Crashlytics (tvOS) - Symbols Still Obfuscated After Uploading DSYMs

Tags: tvos, crashlytics, google-fabric

My tvOS app uses Crashlytics for stack trace reporting. As it is a bitcode built app, I used the steps [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#bitcode-download) to upload the missing dSYMs from iTunes Connect. However, while the Fabric dashboard has crossed off the missing dSYM entry, all of the stack trace data for our app is still reported as *__hidden...*. Not sure where we're going wrong.

For my build settings, I have:

**Deployment Postprocessing** -> **Yes** (for Release configuration)

**Strip Linked/Installed Product** -> **Yes** (for all configurations)

Comment: Hi! Todd from Fabric here. Do you have dwarf w/dSYM set for the debug information format for all build types in your build settings? That would sometimes cause this issue. Are new crashes coming in with the same 'hidden' string in the stack trace?

Comment: Hi Todd! All build types are marked with dwarf w/dSYM, and new crashes are still coming in with the same hidden stacktrace. Not sure if it's relevant, but any native Apple library calls such as with UIKIt, etc. are okay, but anything that's from the app is obfuscated.

Comment: Are you sharing symbols with Apple?

Comment: I believe so. If I go to my app's page on iTunes Connect, "Include Symbols" is marked as "Yes".